# Javascript assignation issue

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I was trying to change the structure of a Javascript object and I don't understand the results I am receiving from the logs.

I have the following object: `a = {e: 1, f: 2}`

And I want to move it to `a.b`

If I do `a.b = a` then I receive these results:

```
console.log(a) // {e: 1, f: 2}
console.log(a.b) // {e: 1, f: 2}
```

While I am expecting something like this:

```
console.log(a) // {b: {e: 1, f: 2}}
console.log(a.b) // {e: 1, f: 2}
```

Can someone explain me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.b = a` simply assigns `a.b` as a reference to `a`, which causes `a` to become a recursive object:

```js
var a = {e: 1, f: 2};
a.b = a;

console.log(a.e, a.f);  //1 2
console.log(a.b.e, a.b.f);  //1 2
console.log(a.b.b.e, a.b.b.f);  //1 2
console.log(a.b.b.b.e, a.b.b.b.f);  //1 2
```

To actually move `a`'s properties into `a.b`, you'll need to overwrite the existing object, assigning a new property `b` to its existing value:

```js
var a = {e: 1, f: 2};

a = {b: a};

console.log(a);  //{b: {e: 1, f: 2}}
```

Comment: In your example the `JSON.parse` `JSON.stringify` combination is not required because you already assigne a new object to `a`.  `a = { b : a}` should have the smae effect.

Comment: Thanks, @t.niese, don't know why i thought the JSON methods were needed.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning a value in JS doesn't *move* it, it copies it.

You are adding a `b` property to the existing object.

It isn't shown in the log because `console.log` protects itself against infinite recursion by not displaying the property.

Comment: Which browser? In Firefox `console.log` does show me `b`.

Comment: @Scimonster — Whatever browser the OP is using.